# RegEx - groups, need [this:andthis] from a string

Tags: regex, preg-match

I hope this is a simple question, but I'm still getting my head around groups.

I have this string: `this is some text [propertyFromId:34] and this is more text` and I will have more like them. I need to get the content between the brackets then a group with the alpha-only text on left of the colon and group with the integer on the right of the colon.

So, full Match: `propertyFromId:34`, Group 1: `propertyFromId`, Group 2: `34`

This is my starting point `(?<=\[)(.*?)(?=])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
\[([a-zA-Z]+):(\d+)]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tW5Faf/1)

**Details**:

- `\[` - a `[` symbol
- `([a-zA-Z]+)` - Group 1 capturing one or more alpha chars (`[[:alpha:]]+` or `\p{L}+` can be used, too)
- `:` - a colon
- `(\d+)` - Group 2 capturing one or more digits
- `]` - a closing `]` symbol.

[PHP demo](http://ideone.com/DF4n4b):

```
$re = '~\[([a-zA-Z]+):(\d+)]~';
$str = 'this is some text [propertyFromId:34] and this is more text';
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
// => Array
//   (
//       [0] => Array
//           (
//               [0] => [propertyFromId:34]
//           )
//   
//       [1] => Array
//           (
//               [0] => propertyFromId
//           )
//   
//       [2] => Array
//           (
//               [0] => 34
//           )
//   
//   )
```